# Visual Studio / Resharper Extract Interface to break god object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring, resharper, automated-refactoring

I'm trying to break a large object into smaller interfaces. Example:

```
public class SomeService
{
    readonly GodObject _god; // <-- Replace this with an Interface

    public SomeService(GodObject god)
    {
        _god = god;
    }

    public string SomeProperty => _god.GetSomeValue();
    public string SomethingElse => _god.SomethingDifferent;
}

public class GodObject
{
    public string GetSomeValue()
    {
        // do something and return
    }
    public string SomethingDifferent { get; set; }

    // Lots and lots more Members
}
```

After the refactoring it should look something like this:

```
public interface IPartialGodObject // <-- Extracted from GodObject
{
    string GetSomeValue();
    string SomethingDifferent { get; }
}

public class SomeService
{
    readonly IPartialGodObject _god; // <-- Now only references the Interface

    public SomeService(IPartialGodObject god)
    {
        _god = god;
    }

    public string SomeProperty => _god.GetSomeValue();
    public string SomethingElse => _god.SomethingDifferent;
}

public class GodObject : IPartialGodObject
{
    //...
}
```

Is Visual Studio or Resharper capable of doing something like this automated? I do know about `Extract Interface`, but with a large object it's quite painful to check only a few Properties/Methods from a large list.

**Update**: To clarify, I only want the members extracted which are used by the `SomeService` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as there is no automated process to do this. What I ended up doing is the following (*Resharper 2018*):

1. `Extract Interface`
2. `Select Public`
3. Replaced the member in question with the new interface
4. Go to the interface and rely on *Resharper's "Property is never used"* to delete all unused properties